# WebApi - Tokens vs Cookies

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api, token

I’m working on an existing single-page application consuming data from WebAPI.

Authentication is largely handled with WebSecurity and SimpleMembership via forms authentication as the application was originally built on MVC.

I know that this is bad (CSRF), and I want to fix it either by

- implementing some kind of CSRF protection (preferred)
- or by reimplementing Authentication and Authorization to use tokens instead of cookies.

Would implementing [header validation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks) be an adequate solution?  The API is being consumed by both web and mobile clients, in case it matters.

I’m not too skilled around security and want to make sure we’re not setting ourselves up for vulnerability by using cookies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would have to leave cookies anyway because otherwise you wouldn't be able to authenticate returning users (they would have to authenticate every time they open the app page). (Of course there are other exotic options like using client local storage or "Flash cookies" but this is pretty much the same approach.)

To answer your question, yes, you will need to implement CSRF protection. It doesn't matter which implementation you choose: it can be the implementation that uses custom HTTP headers or additional WebAPI request params, it can be implemented using built-in anti-forgery API (described in the article you mentioned) or you can make your own implementation.

I would probably implement custom CSRF protection mechanism because this way you can make it more suitable for your SPA (for example you can send it through WebAPI response as a result of authentication operation instead of rendering it to the HTML or JS as it was suggested in the article).

Comment: Awesome!  That's reassuring as I'd definitely prefer to avoid doing a lot of rework here.  So `cookies` + `csrf protection` is just as good as `tokens` from a security standpoint?

Comment: Yes, authentication cookies + ASP.NET AntiForgery (which by the way also uses its own cookie, see https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/Internal/DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore.cs or http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/AntiForgeryTokenStore.cs for previous version of ASP.NET) is as good as tokens from a security standpoint because ASP.NET AntiForgery is essentially a token itself: it is per-client, it is generated on the server and it is validated on the server.

Comment: By the way, if you use ASP.NET Core on the server side you can set up AntiForgery middleware to use HTTP headers instead of form fields like this: `services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = yourHeaderName);`. This way you would be able to reuse default validator instead of writing your own.